# OAuth Issue for Connecting to Twitter API to make user search (users/search)

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

I am using Twitter API for retrieving user information for specific name searches. The method I am using is users/search. You can find details of this method here: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-users-search.

Right now I am trying to use OAuth in my application as Twitter announced that they will no longer support basic authentication. The issue with using QAuth is that I don't require the users to connect to their Twitter account and so I can not generate user token. My application is using Twitter just for showing information about people, it's not posting/updating anything. I will really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on using OAuth for Twitter without using Twitter user's login information.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create an account for your application and use that account to perform user search if your application is a webapp.

If your application is an desktop app, I think it's understandable to user that they need to authorize your application to do the user search.